# Unable to create secret api key for Google maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, generative-adversarial-network

I am working with pix2pix neural network and need to generate some data from google maps. The script requires API Key and Secret API Key.

I tried to enable restrictions on my API (to my IP) however I am definitely doing smth wrong. I can't find any new Key created.

If any more info needed I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (API) Key is shown in both screenshots and begins `AIza`.

**You should delete the API Key that you included in the screenshots and create another**

Please be **very** careful about sharing data like this because it is a so-called bearer token which means that anyone (the bearer) who has it can use it (although you are trying to enforce API and IP restrictions which is good practice).

It's possible someone could infer the entire key from both screenshots that you've included. Deleting it will void it. Please create another and don't share it with anyone that doesn't require it.

I'm unfamiliar with pix2pix but **all** API keys should be treated as secret(s). Google only provides one value for API keys so there's no "API Key" **and** "Secret API Key" **only** "API Key" that should always be treated as secrets.